# Create a copy of objects pointed to by elements of a vector of shared_pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a class `customClass1` with a property that is a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<customClass2>>`.

How can I make a copy of a `customClass1` object that contains pointers to *identical copies* of the objects pointed to by the elements of the first `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<customClass2>>`?

I *don't* want to simply make copies of the pointers contained in the vector. I want to actually make copies of the objects that the pointers are pointing to, and then have pointers to these new objects stored in my second `customClass1` object's vector property.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking about. A shared pointer can be dereferenced (e.g. using the `*` operator) to create a copy of the contained object, that these are stored in a vector seems mostly irrelevant.

Comment: I guess I'm asking if there is a way to do it without iterating through each element and dereferencing, i.e. automatically create copies of the pointed-to objects, but with new pointers.

Comment: No, that's not possible. A simple copy of the vector copies the shared_ptr's not the objects contained by them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are going to have to do is iterate through the vector you want to copy and create new `shared_ptr`s that have the same value as the underlying object in the vector you are copying from.  You can do that with:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<customClass2>> original; // this has the data to copy
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<customClass2>> copy;
copy.reserve(original.size()); // prevent reallocations

for (const auto& e : original)
    copy.push_back(std::make_shared<customClass2>(*e));
```

If you are dealing with a polymorphic type this will slice the object as you have a pointer to the base so only the bass part will be copied.  If you are working with a polymorphic type you can create a `virtual` clone function and use `clone()` to copy the object.  For more on this see [What is a “virtual constructor”?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions#virtual-ctors) on the [isocpp.org FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq)

Comment: So I have to iterate manually through the vector and dereference to create the copies? Is there no way to automatically create copies of the pointed-to objects, but with new pointers? What if I used `unique_pointer`?

Comment: @NewDogOldTricks Than you would not be able to copy it at all.

Comment: @NewDogOldTricks That would be the same situation.  You could do this with `std::tranform` but it would basically be the same thing and you would need to use a lambda to make the copy.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you, that makes sense!

Comment: A `reserve` up-front and a brief mention of the potential of slicing would be nice.

Comment: @T.C. I have updated the answer.  I wasn't even thinking about that in this case.  Let me know if that covers it for you.